# Using Selenium with Java on Salesforce Lightning / Javascript problems

Tags: selenium, salesforce-lightning

We had Selenium tests running on Sales Force non Lightning.  Now I am converting to Lightning.  There is a chain of menus to go through.  I have successfully navigated to a certain menu, but now I have run into a problem.  This is not the standard question about new element names.  Here is the question.  This is a small piece of what the page looks like (see below).

[image]

When using inspect with Chrome I can find the elements.  This is what it looks like (a small cross section corresponding to above).  The SPAN tag has the label ("Original Agreement") and the  DIV below it will contain the box for the input value.

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control" data-aura-rendered-by="228:1224;a">
 <div data-aura-rendered-by="1108:0" class="uiInput forceSearchInputLookupDesktop uiInput--default" data-aura-class="uiInput forceSearchInputLookupDesktop uiInput--default">
  <label class="label inputLabel uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel" for="157:1224;a" data-aura-rendered-by="1103:0" data-aura-class="uiLabel">
   <span class="" data-aura-rendered-by="1104:0">Original Agreement</span>
   <!--render facet: 1106:0--><!--render facet: 1107:0--></label>
   <div data-aura-rendered-by="161:1224;a"><div class="contentWrapper slds-box--border" data-aura-rendered-by="162:1224;a">
```

However, Selenium can not find the elements (though inspect does).  When I did a "View Page Source instead of an
inspect, almost the entire thing is in JavaScript like this:

```
function rewriteAndInjectCss(linkEl, source, varLookup) {
    var css = rewriteCssVars(source, varLookup);
    injectStyles(linkEl, css);
}
```

but a lot more. Almost all functions, with maybe only a couple elements.

In the past when I have seen something similar there is often an iframe to switch to to get the elements.  But there is no iframe to switch to.  So I am stuck how to get these.  Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: once focused on the input right-click and choose "inspect element".

Comment: that won't help Selenium find the elements.

Comment: it'll give you the input tag you need to target... after clicking/focusing on the div (contentWrapper)

Comment: OK.  Found it.  I needed to do a driver.switchTo().defaultContent()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Found it. I needed to do a driver.switchTo().defaultContent()